# Filter "need answers" questions: hide questions I've down-voted / close-voted

Tags: feature-request, tags, filtering

I try to use the "**Need Answers**" tab for specific tags, because I think it's a great idea / way to make sure Stack Overflow is *the* place for questions. However, it's not working too well at the moment:

1. **The tab shows several questions I've voted to close**. As far as I'm concerned those questions are not in need of an answer, but in need of more close votes.
2. **The tab shows several questions I've downvoted**. Sure, 80% of the cases these also fall in category 1, but those other 20% rarely get edited after my downvote, and it's very unlikely I'll answer a question I've downvoted.
3. <strike>**The tab shows questions with answers.**</strike> It seems (*after some delay*) the system filters questions with at least one answer I've upvoted. This is great! Similar smart filters would be nice for case 1 and 2, above...

I know this would make this "Needs Answers" tab more useful to me.

Your thoughts?