# The "Need Answers" filter isn't working properly and/or as expected

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, new-nav, filtering

I've created a custom filter for:

- Tag filter: [knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockoutjs)
- Additional filter: **need answers**
- Order by: **newest**

This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of the filter]

This makes absolutely zero sense to me :-). I've [asked a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306862/419956) before, but in this case as far as I can tell there's also this case getting through my "*need answers*" filter: **questions with an accepted (often even upvoted) answers**.

Please improve the "need answers" filter, at least to the point where question with an accepted answer are removed.

PS. I do realize there is some value in providing competing answers, even when the asker already marked one as accepted, but if I click the "need answers" filter I'm not expecting mostly questions of that type.

Comment: I'd recall that "Unanswered" tab includes answered questions when there are not upvoted  answers, maybe this is related?

Comment: @Teemu I kind of touch upon that in linked question. However, in the screenshot from this question, there are questions that have answers that are upvoted, accepted, or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).